# Displaying all images from directory

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am trying to display images from directory , all images are loading but there are not showing , just a box of size i defined through coding .

First here is my code.

```
 string imagepath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/");
        string[] images =Directory.GetFiles(imagepath,"*.png",SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

        foreach (string filepath in images)
        {

            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image te = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();                
            te.ImageUrl = filepath;
            te.Height = 100;
            te.Width = 200;
            //Here myimages is my div in which all images will be added.
            myimages.Controls.Add(te);



        }
```

Now the screen shot what i am getting .
link below:
http://pages.apunkashaher.com/error.html

So, any one can help out what is missing ?

Comment: If you debug it step by step (that is faster than write that question) you see that on this point `ImageUrl = filepath` you set the local file name, something like `c:\inetpub\site\images\image.png`, now this you need to change it to  `/images/image.png`

Comment: Can you provide any help on that

Comment: View your source in HTML on the page and you'll see the images pointing to the wrong location, you need to fix the ImageUrl in your code so it's relative as Aristos says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string imagepath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/");
        string[] images =Directory.GetFiles(imagepath,"*.png",SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

        foreach (string filepath in images)
        {


            Image te = new Image();

            string fileurl = Path.GetFileName(filepath.ToString());

            te.ImageUrl = "~/Images/" + fileurl;
            te.Height = 100;
            te.Width = 200;
            te.CssClass = "zoom";
            //Here myimages is my div in which all images will be added.
            myimages.Controls.Add(te);



        }
```

Hence Solved & Working.

Answer (score -1):

I'd check what links the images are actually rendering in HTML by viewing the source, I suspect that the code is finding the images but that you are not rendering the correct URL for the browser.